# Streamlining workflow of Express and Jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I am currently working on a project that uses MongoDB, Express, and Jade. We always want to throw the user account JSON data into the view. Every single controller we have, we are writing

```
exports.theView = function(req, res){
    User.findOne({ username: req.user.username }, function(err, user){
        res.render('theview.jade', { user: user });
    });
}
```

There seems like there should be a better, more efficient way of doing this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use middleware to set response locals (http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) to set user to view every reqeust.

Middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ username: req.user.username }, function(err, user){
         res.locals.user = req.user;
         next()
    });
});
```

Route:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('theview.jade', {title: 'Title'});  
});
```

View:

```
block content
  h1= title
  p= user.name
```